# PDO::bindParam on nonexistent parameter?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm creating a User object and the constructor pulls user data from the database when the object is created. Its set up so that it can pull data either by knowing the UserID or the user's email.

```
function __construct ($db_obj, $userID=0) {
    $this->_db_obj = $db_obj;
    if (is_numeric ($userID))
        $where_str = "userID = $userID";
    else
        $where_str = "user_email LIKE :user_email";
    $get_user_obj = $db_obj->prepare ("SLECT * FROM Users WHERE $where_str");
    $get_user_obj->bindParam (":user_email", $userID);
    $get_user_obj->execute();

    // Do some stuff
}
```

Is it allowable to use a bindParam method on a parameter that may not be there? Is it better for me to just split this into two different functions (which would seem to go against the DRY principle)?

Comment: Why not set a flag variable and add another `if` statement? Or just copy the `if (is_numeric ($userID))` down to short-circuit the `bindParam()` call?

Comment: Another option (since I'm full of them) is to first validate the `$userID` argument value, then use `userID = $userID OR user_email LIKE '$userID'`, since it doesn't appear one could be mistaken for the other.